# Пишу тг Бота на aiogram 3, во время введения системы оплаты, ошибок в коде PyCharm не выдаёт, но при активации происходит ошибка START_PARAM_INVALID

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram-3.x

Вот кусок кода, в котором он и видит ошибку. Заранее спасибо за помощь:

```py
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.types import Message, LabeledPrice, PreCheckoutQuery


async def order(message:Message, bot: Bot):
    await bot.send_invoice(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        title="Оплата рекламы вашего объявления",
        description= 'После оплаты в течении 5-15 минут в группе будет выложен пост с вашим товаром.',
        payload='Payment',
        provider_token= '381764678:TEST:69972',
        currency= 'rub',
        prices=[
            LabeledPrice(
                label='Размещение Объявления',
                amount=55000
            ),
            #LabeledPrice(
            #   label='НДС',
            #    amount=5500
            #),
            LabeledPrice(
                label='Скидка',
                amount=55000

            )
        ],
        start_parameter='Fount Of Discounts',
        photo_url='https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/019/595/159/large/ian-pestridge-vanguard.jpg?1564182626',
        photo_size= 100,
        photo_width= 1080,
        photo_height= 1148,
        send_phone_number_to_provider= True,
        is_flexible= False,
        disable_notification= True,
        allow_sending_without_reply= True,
        request_timeout=30
    )
async def pre_checkout_query(precheckoutquery: PreCheckoutQuery, bot: Bot):
    await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query.id, ok=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо заменить строку

```py
start_parameter='Fount Of Discounts',
```

на

```py
start_parameter='fount-of-discounts',
```

---

[Пример из документации другой библиотеки (54 строка)](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/payments_example.py)